# React IDE installation

Tags: reactjs, reactide

I want to use React IDE developign environment:

```
https://reactide.io/
```

But now word about installation instructions. And no windows installers can see. Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://github.com/reactide/reactide

Answer (score 0):

There's no installer for it. You need to go here: https://github.com/reactide/reactide and follow the steps described in the  README file. (git checkout, install etc...)

On another note I recommend you to use https://code.visualstudio.com/. This is what I'm currently using when developing react-apps.

Answer (score 0):

How to install Reactide environment:

[image: how install Reactide environment]

Comment: Hi. your images carry more info than pure text descriptions can. That is why I made it visible for you. However, please do add a textual description, in order to make your answer accessible to those who cannot interpret pictures.